# Ping-pong bot for StackExchange

Tags: code-golf

## History

There's a room on StackOverflow in Russian where you can see such an interesting discussion:

> [image]

Just because there are not enough real discussing in that room, @Grundy "plays ping-pong" to keep it unfrozen.

## Task

Implement a bot for StackExchange that posts "ping!" to the 115624 room if the previous message was "pong!" **(and posted by another user) and "pong!" if the previous message was "ping!" (and posted by another user).
If you need a login and a password for SE account, use `l` and `p`.

<sub>**It should not reply to its own messages</sub>

## Rules

Code-golf: the shortest answer wins.

*Nice golfing!*

Comment: The idea is kinda fun but could it be considered a borderline [malicious code](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4829/should-asking-for-malicious-code-be-on-topic)? Using sockpuppet accounts may also be a problem. (But I don't really know for sure.)

Comment: @Arnauld No. Firstly you can use _your own_ account. And... using an additional account for your bot is not considered a violation if you don't break [these rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388984/what-are-the-rules-governing-multiple-accounts-i-e-sockpuppets).

Comment: @Arnauld Sockpuppet accounts are allowed for chat bots (assuming they don't break any normal rules), but I would recommend creating your own chatroom for this, rather than spamming into a different chatroom (even if that's what the room is for)

Comment: Furthermore, I would *highly* recommend that you start using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) for your challenge ideas

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing oh yeah you're right. Grundy don't like bots in his chatroom.

Comment: I'd recommend posting the messages to room 1 (sandbox). You can put bots and do basically whatever you want there because it's just the place for anyone to test anything (that isn't spam/R/A of course)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing (and Victor) Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: [Very similar, but more complex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32615/create-a-chatbot-for-the-stack-exchange-chatrooms)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, _"plays ping-pong" to keep it unfrozen._ that's wrong guess

Comment: Oh, hello @Grundy. It is not a guess I asked a question on meta ru.SO and the answer said ping-pong is the way to keep a room unfrozen. Is not it?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, so, logically, that's a wrong answer :-)

Comment: @Grundy and what is the correct one?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor the Secret (¬‿¬)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor nope (￣_,￣ )

Comment: this room cannot freeze...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody golfs... so:

## Python 3 — 330 byte

```
from chatexchange.client import Client
s=Client("stackexchange.com");s.login('l','p');r=s.get_room('115624');r.join();o=lambda e,_:r.send_message("ping!")if e.message.content_source=='pong!'and e.user.id!=483667 else r.send_message('pong!')if e.message.content_source=='ping!'and e.user.id!=483667 else 0;r.watch_socket(o)
while 1:0
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the `chatexchange` module?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing [`pip3 install chatexchange`](https://pypi.org/project/ChatExchange/)